# Virtual printer in windows, where to start?

Tags: windows, printing, pdf-generation, drivers

I want to write a program (or a driver) on windows that can:
- Display on printer list when user open print dialog
- Display an optional dialog for config printing
- Print to a file
In short, my need is very close to pdf printers which can print any document to pdf file.
Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have almost answered your own question: I would look at one of the open source implementations and see how they do it:

PDF Creator for example.

Browse code online: http://pdfcreator.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pdfcreator/trunk/

Check it out: `svn co http://pdfcreator.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/pdfcreator/trunk`

Perhaps once you have a more specific question you can come back here and ask.